# What other means disable Reinhardt's shield except hack and cool down?

Tags: overwatch

Since the season 3 patch happened, it happens to me that Reinhardt's shield gets on some occasions a 2~3 second cool down. I couldn't make it out when it happens exactly, but most of the time it happens after I run into something with my charge.

I already made sure that this isn't due to my shield recently breaking, nor had I been hacked. I can't remember if it ever happened to a full shield, but it definetly happened when the shield had at most 900hp left (so not whats the case if it had broken)

I couldn't find any patch notes about it so far, 
so is anything known about this behavior? Is it atually some kind of undocumented feature?
Or might this even be a bug? In this case, what is the exact situation triggering this bug to happen?

**Bounty related examples:**

- 1<sup>st</sup> I charged to pin a D.VA in front of me who just started her ult the moment I hit shift. I made a short distance charge leaving the mech in a devastating position. since I just hit it and the charge was short I tried to raise my shield. it didn't work. I checked if the shield symbol has a CD bar filling or some kind of disabled symbol like sombras ability hack.
  shield charge? 2000/2000 I pressed the mouse key deep and hard... no response. I started spamming RMB to not miss the moment shield being on again.... boom D.VA just made a penta kill as the team relied on me raising my shield....
- 2<sup>nd</sup> I charged a Zarya and just got hooked by Roadhog the moment I entered the wall-impact animation. Same as above. No indication was displayed hinting informations that the shield should be disabled or when it will be back again. this time ti was somewhere around ~1200 but still I got killed before the shield was raisable again.
- 3<sup>rd</sup> A Mei placing a wall within my charge. Me and my team got heavily fired at after this I wasn't able to raise my shield for 1~1.5 seconds. Luckily after spamming it this time we survived it.

**I finally made it to capture that one.**

Here is the video:

note: I tried from the moment of impact on to raise my shield. You will also notice how I was spamming my right mouse button until the shield is available again due to the shield I raise and immediately let it drop again, before I finally raise it.

And I see no reason why the shield shouldn't be available between 0:12~0:14

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say you weren't hacked, you're including Sombra's ultimate as well?

Comment: @Powerlord: No, it only happens when I'm hit by Sombra's ult. Its so weird. *sarcasm off* yeah for sure I include her ult. Not to mention that all the symbols and red light are quite flashy, where as I say in OP that there are no visual indicators at all, that my shield shouldn't work. But I'm about to try to record it the next time it happens.

Comment: Is there any chance that it could be lag? High ping or packet loss might cause you to take an extra couple milliseconds to raise your shield, and even the strongest internet connections can slow down for a fraction of a second occasionally.

Comment: @MageXy: Well, from the way it behaves it could be. But please take me literaly with my descriptions. I'm not speaking about a time frame of a fraction of a second. I'm speaking about SECONDS. Also it just happened after a somewhat intevened charge, yet. So while this might be, I doubt that. Anyways, lemme see when playing a bit more this weekend, if I can finally make it to record it.

Comment: @Zaibis I did some testing last night and could not replicate the cool-down timer showing up on the shield. There is however a slight time difference in the shield coming up depending on whether or not you hit something. It seems like you can't start the raise shield animation until after you have completed whatever animation is currently playing (ie: Rein shrugging off the impact of hitting a wall). Do you have any screenshots or videos showing the issue?

Comment: @Zaibis You'd be surprised by how many people overlook things like that.

Comment: @Malco Hmmm Couldn't reproduce it so far. But I was testing a bit too and figured out it the main problem seems to come from a hook interrupting the charge. I'm not quiet sure but it feels like the (lets call it animation after your findings) animation after being hooked takes different times until the hook can be raised again. I was trying to figure out if the mini stun after roadhoag hook maybe is somewhat ping relying. But maybe there are situational different animations after being hooked mid charge?

Comment: @Zaibis do you play with net stats turned on and visible? If so what is your average ping while playing? It is possible that network latency is playing a role here, but unless you are on dial-up it shouldn't be responsible for the literal seconds of delay you describe in the question.

Comment: @Malco: Yes I do but I wasn't able to reproduce it on the degree I had in the mentioned cases before. Usually I have 30~50.

Comment: @Malco: I managed to capture it.

Comment: I single-framed through this several times.  The shield icon turns white at 0:12 while you are still in third person.  I'm not sure if that's the correct behavior, or if it's supposed to wait until you are in first person.  Regardless, I imagine that the server and client could have disagreed about the exact duration of your charge animation and just did the best interpolation they could, but there's really no evidence of that.

Comment: @Kevin: I take it as you confirm, this recording shows it is a bug?

Comment: *shrug* I don't know.  Probably something is wrong, but I can't tell if it's "The UI lied to you about when the shield was ready" or "the shield failed to engage" or maybe even "the client thought the shield was ready before the server agreed."

Comment: @Kevin: Well the UI is lying, too. As you are right that the shield is just available when back in first person. But thats not the problem here. The problem is the full second after it. It is hard to reproduce, so it probably isn't the intended behavior. and 1 second as Reinhardt without the shield, were one would expect the shield to be up, you just had too look my hp bar over that one second and you could agree how crucial the shield is for that time. And if it is some kind of sync problem, is there anything I could do to fix it?

Comment: It's entirely possible it was a bug or something. Rein's shield hasn't exactly been on its best behavior recently. I also noticed I can't E with Symetra while looking down too much but it wasn't the same for Rein.

Comment: @Zaibis This is really strange, nothing is immediately apparent about why it is happening. It looks like a pretty standard Rein charge, you just get a little nudged at the start of it. The video does do a great job of capturing what is going on, but this question might be a little to technical in nature for anyone here to answer. Now that you have a video I would recommend posting either on [official Blizzard forums](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/22813881/), or [r/overwatch](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/) if you haven't already. Hopefully you can get a Blizz dev to answer.

Comment: @Malco: https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/71bg5p/bug_reinhardt_shield_occasionally_not_working/?ref=share&ref_source=link Well, I tryed it but I have the impression I'm not used enough to redit to make even anyone paying attentnion on this. Have not even a clue how to embed the video. And Blizzard forums.... did they ever react there on anything at all? IDK... posting and pushing this there allready for longer as this SE post exists...

Comment: @Zaibis You can't embed videos into the Reddit posts, your post looks fine though. Now you just need to hope for the best, and that your post will gain traction. Blizzard does watch their forums, but an actual support ticket might be best as that way you will at least get _some_ kind of response.

Comment: could it be that the game is waiting for the length of the charge animation before doing any other? So, let's say that full length charge takes 3 seconds. If you would start the charge and hit a wall or fortified Orisa or whatever else after 1 second, the game would force you to wait for the full length charge animation before using your shield? In this example, you wouldn't be able to use your shield for another 2 seconds. Anyway, this looks like a bug, the best would be to contact Blizzard and ask them to fix it

Comment: @Novarg: hmmmm I at least couldn't exclude that assumption. But also have n proof for it. Btw there are even more strange things going on with rein since last patch... 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HI_ZBRVcgww

Comment: @Zaibis oh, that looks... Buggy? Although this video speaks against my speculation of charge animation and shield. Maybe I should play Rein more to discover any other bugs

Answer (score 1):

Ex-reinhardt main here, the issue is a map issue and has happened to me before on xbox 1 albeit a while ago.

What is happening is that when you finish charging and return to regular state, your facing the wall directly and as you go to pull out the sheild it literally has nowhere at all to go, even thought it will usually clip into a wall. I believe it does not occur anymore, but I might be mistaken. Usually when you pull out your sheild in such a scenario you either move back slightly, or it clips slightly into the wall, if you watch closely when you first pull out the shield it does not touch any walls (approx 0.14seconds in) then shortly after clips to the side as you move back.

You should also check your keyboard and mouse inputs and make sure they are as responsive as they should be, there is always the chance of issues with:

- Key Actuation
- Mouse response times
- Lag and delay

With any sort of blizzard game it is best to ask their support team (I believe you have from the comment you made on this post but just incase), they are very responsive and helpful, everyone their is a kind person and you will also find that a lot of them know what they are talking about with the games. Your best chance at a pinpoint accurate response is sending in a blizzard support ticket, and that even leaves the chance of them fixing it if it is a genuine bug, you can also post a bug report on the forums.

Heres the links to do so:
https://eu.battle.net/support/en/games/overwatch [Blizzard Support]
https://eu.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/ [Official Overwatch Forum]

Answer (score -10):

I do not know when this was added, but now, when the shield breaks, there is a 5 second cooldown added to the shield.

Comment: This has been in the game since release, and I quote from the question: "I already made sure that this isn't due to my shield recently breaking"